# Why am I not able to update Ubuntu 20.04.3?

Tags: apt, 20.04, upgrade, updates

When I run `sudo apt-get update` in terminal, I get the following output:

```
Ign:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                         
Err:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty Release                        
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1562::1c 80]
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal InRelease       
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease                 
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

It seems to be searching a repository for Zesty even though the current version is 20.04.3 Focal Fossa. I have been unable to get updates or upgrade from Focal to the most recent Ubuntu Distribution.

Comment: Somehow, you have added zesty (Ubuntu 17.04) repositories to your Ubuntu 20.04. See [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Yes. that seemed to do the trick. Only thing different was the interface of software & updates, but doing the equivalent steps seems to have worked.